# How do I handle null pointer exception in java applet?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, applet, awt, cardlayout

I am running a simple applet in my machine.Note that when executing applet "Null pointer exception" error occurs when the applet is trying to run. The below code is shown

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.math.*;

<applet code="s09_04" width=300 height=50>
</applet>

public class s09_04 extends Applet
{

  CardLayout c1;
  Panel p;
  Label l1;
  Label l2;
  Label l3;
  Label l4;
  TextField t1;
  TextField t2;
  TextField t3;
  TextField t4;

  public void start()
  {

  }

  public void init()
  {
    c1 = new CardLayout();
    l1 = new Label("Enter Name :");
    l2 = new Label("Enter Place :");
    l3 = new Label("Address :");
    l4 = new Label("Pin :670571 ");
    t1 = new TextField(20);
    p = new Panel();
    p.setLayout(c1);
    add(l1);
    add(t1);
    add(l2);
    add(t2);
    add(l3);
    add(t3);
    add(l4);
    add(t4);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {

  }
}
```

The command used are

javac s09_04.java

and

appletviewer s09_04.java.

Terminal output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1037)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:373)
    at s09_04.init(s09_04.java:32)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

My question is what is most likely reason that applet is failing to start??When does null pointer exception occur???What is the reason for causing null pointer exception??And what should i change in my code so that code runs smoothly without any error.Any suggestions/changes in code would be appreciated.note that i am running this code in linux .thanks...

Comment: you can use `try-catch-finally` block for exception handling to avoid application being stopped

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 0):

Because `TextField t2, t3 and t4;` is not initialized. resolve by

```
t2=new TextField(20);
t3=new TextField(20);
t4=new TextField(20);
```

like t1

Comment: But when applet is executed the details wont be stored...Any idea how to store details ??

Comment: What details wont stored?

Comment: like when i enter name into that textfield the details have to be stored...but it is not getting stored...

Comment: Take a look http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

Answer (score 0):

**most likely reason that applet is failing to start??**

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) of the `Applet` says to add a component to the `Container`, that should be initialised.

Here, in the code, `t2, t3, t4` are not initialised, which throw `NullPointerException`

**When does null pointer exception occur???**

That's a very big topic and simply in one line,

When you try to access a object which is not initialised, then it throws NPE(see the example)

```
Object o = null;
// o is not initialised.
o.wait();
```

**what should i change in my code so that code runs smoothly without any error**

Initialise all the components which you are trying to add to Applet.

```
t2=new TextField(20);
t3=new TextField(20);
t4=new TextField(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Declare TextField `TextField t2;TextField t3;TextField t4;` but not initialize in `init()` initialize a `t2,t3,t4`. You are adding `add(t2);add(t3);add(t4); //Here The Exception`

```
         t2=new TextField(20);
         t3=new TextField(20);
         t3=new TextField(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

but if you are not initializing Text fields means with out giving it any space how could it can store the data?

so try this.

```
t2=new TextField(size);
t3=new TextField(size);
t3=new TextField(size);
```

it will help.